# Find middle element in Count sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

So, I have array like this:

```
a[1] = 2
a[4] = 3
a[8] = 1
```

which represent this sequence `1 1 4 4 4 8`

And I need to find middle element, or element before (for odd and even);
In this example its 4.

How can I do this quick?

My code is very slow:

```
static int B(int[] array, int size) {       
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i]; j++) {
            c++;
            if (c == size / 2) {
                return i;    
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you access to the (a.length / 2) value after rounding it ?

Comment: @BaileyS What you mean? I will use this array, but I need to find middle element

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin  Show us something more clear. May be some example or some code that you tried.

Comment: @Smit  Some code addded

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin So your array contains `1 1 4 4 4 8`. that means 6 elements. (a.length / 2)  this will work to get middle element in array for odd number of elements. but waht you gonna do if length is even like in your current example.`for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { if(i == size/2) return array[i]` will work

Comment: I dont want create new array like `1 1 1 4 4 4 8` from my original array! This is the problem.

Comment: I can only think on a dynamic programming algorithm to solve this, but since this looks like homework, it would be better if you find the way to solve it by your own.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be that slow, even though the 'j' loop is unnecessary. Are your input arrays very large?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Traverse original array and add all values

   ```
   a[1] = 2
   a[4] = 3
   a[8] = 1
   sum = 6
   ```
2. Divide sum by 2 (find mid)

   ```
   mid = 6/2 = 3
   ```
3. Traverse original array and subtract value from sum

   ```
   check if ans <= 0
   if true print index
   else continue to next
   ```

Comment: Easy method that takes at most O(N). Keep that rate.

Answer (score 0):

For an even less efficient way to do it, run one pass through and keep updating :)

Javascript (since I'm Java challenged):

```
var a=[]

a[1] = 2
a[4] = 3
a[8] = 1
a[9] = 2
a[10] = 3
a[11] = 1
//1 1 4 4 4 8 9 9 10 10 10 11

function middle (arr){
  var stack = [],
      total = 0,
      tmp,
      tmpChange,
      middle = 0,
      change = 0,
      middleElement

  for (i in arr){
    stack.push([i, arr[i]])
    total += arr[i]
    tmp = Math.ceil(total/2)
    change = tmp - middle
    middle = tmp

    while (change){
      tmpChange = stack[0][1] - change

      if (tmpChange >= 0) {
        stack[0][1] = tmpChange
        change = 0
      }
      else {
        change -= stack[0][1]
        stack.splice(0,1) 
      }
    }

    middleElement = stack[0][0]
  }

  return middleElement
}

console.log(middle(a))
```